# Vim color scheme overriding the background settings in Gnome Terminal

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have set my gnome-terminal's background to dark-blue, with a bit of transparency so I can see the underlying webpages or other documents when I code.

I've been using the smyck color scheme, which appears to be my terminal background as its background, so it looks seamless when I enter Vim.

[image: my terminal window on top of a web page]
(my terminal window on top of a web page)

[image: the very same terminal window entering vim]
(the very same terminal window entering vim)

Lately I decided to switch to some other color scheme. As I was trying out jellybeans, I noticed that it has overridden my default terminal background settings, both its color and transparency, as you can see below.

[image: the very same terminal window entering vim now with jellybeans]
(the very same terminal window entering vim now with jellybeans)

I have installed the AfterColors plugin, but I don't know where to start to tweak the color scheme to have the default background back. Any suggestioins?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Set the ctermbg to none:

```
hi Normal ctermbg=none
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like a good start. Where can I find more information on the `:highlight` command? It looks like only setting the background color of "Normal" won't cut it completely, leaving some trivial areas unaffected.

Comment: great! I found that if you type only `:highlight`, you will get a list of all the current highlight options with live example, which is very helpful!

Comment: Thanks! I'd been looking for a solution to this problem for a long time :)

Comment: For anyone else that may be looking. On NeoVIm sometimes you have to set guibg to none as well. `hi Normal guibg=none`

Comment: If you are adding these to your .vimrc you need to place them after `syntax on`

Answer (score 44):

In addtional of perreal's answer, you also need to

`highlight NonText ctermbg=none`

this will help make other "nothing exist" region to be transparent.

Comment: The other answer isn't complete without this answer. If only both could be jointly accepted as the correct answer...

Comment: I'll also add if anyone wants their line number non-transparent, that is done via `highlight LineNr ctermbg=none`